# I have deleted All Files in server Still Site is working?

Tags: webserver, cpanel

I have deleted all Files in Server using both Cpanel File Manger .
But still Site is Running . What will be the reason? .

I have cleared all cache.

I am having 2 servers '.com' and other one is '.no'
Both have same IP Address ?
if you go to '.com' it will redirect to '.no' site

I have logged in to cpanel using sitename.no:2082 and deleted all files but .. site is working perfectly.

What is working like this ... How can I able to find out issue ?

Thank you is advance.

Comment: The webserver or an intermediate proxy will have it in its own cache? Try to restart the webserver process.

Comment: If your website is serving static HTML files then a proxy server may have cached your entire website before you deleted it. This is quite common especially on a dial-up connection because the ISPs "speed up" your web browsing by caching content on a server which is physically close to you rather than waiting to be routed to the real web server.

Comment: @Lambert I am uploading and deleted Joomla site it is dynamic site. I am not deleted database but I have deleted all files ,

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I am uploading and deleted Joomla site it is dynamic site. I am not deleted database but I have deleted all files ,

Comment: You will also want to ask Google to delete the pages.  It can take about 24 hours, if I remember right.